Is the verb "adhere" transitive?
I checked several dictionary, and they all say "adhere" is intransitive. I didn't see one saying "adhere" is transitive.
For example, The stamp adhered to the envelope.
However, Google book has hits saying "adhere it to a surface" or  "adhere it to the card".
Can I say "I adhered the stamp to the envelope"?

I cannot see your 'hits'. It is possible that Google Books contains some mistaken usages. These may be by people who confuse 'adhere' with 'stick', or who think that 'adhere' is more high-falutin', or direct speech by such a person, e.g. in a novel. A very good reference, the Oxford English Dictionary, has only intransitive definition of the verb 'adhere'. Likewise Cambridge Dictionary.

The Merriam-Webster dictionary has a transitive definition and transitive uses in their "recent uses" section. That said, I think it's somewhat controversial and I personally wouldn't use "adhere" in this way.

Development similar to "stick".  A stamp sticks to an envelope because the stamp has some glue on the back.  "Stick the stamp on the envelope."

Perhaps it's used as a transitive verb in some Google books, but it's really only ever used as an intransitive verb. You would not say that you "adhered the post-it note to the chart." You would use the verb "stick":

I stuck the post-it note to the chart.
I stuck the stamp on the envelope.

